# Plot the route between multiple markers using MapBox

Tags: javascript, routes, leaflet, mapbox

I'm using MapBox API to create different maps. I have around 25 markers with latitude and longitude information for each marker. I'm able to plot the markers on the map. Now I want to draw the road connecting these markers. Can someone let me know how to do this using MapBox API.

Below is the html code that I am using to plot the markers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    .map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.my-icon {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.icon-dc {
  background: #3ca0d3;
}

.icon-sf {
  background: #63b6e5;
}

</style>

<div id='map-two' class='map'> </div>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = '<your access token>';
var mapTwo = L.mapbox.map('map-two', 'mapbox.light')
.setView([12.9716,77.5946], 20);

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(mapTwo);

var geojson = [
  {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [77.5048747113, 13.0408676171]
    },
    properties: {
      icon: {
        className: 'my-icon icon-dc', // class name to style
        html: '&#9733;', // add content inside the marker
        iconSize: null // size of icon, use null to set the size in CSS
      }
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [77.5045504332, 13.0386169339]
    },
    properties: {
      icon: {
        className: 'my-icon icon-sf', // class name to style
        html: '&#9733;', // add content inside the marker
        iconSize: null // size of icon, use null to set the size in CSS
      }
    }
  }
];

myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
  var marker = e.layer,
    feature = marker.feature;
  marker.setIcon(L.divIcon(feature.properties.icon));
});
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);

mapTwo.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to plot the route between the markers.

Thanks.

Comment: I will show you an example soon

Comment: Have you tried the mapbox direction API ?

Comment: @Manuel, It would be great if you can show an example.

Comment: oke i will do ! today or tomorrow morning

Comment: @Manuel, thanks for your interest. Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: and did it worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [mapbox directions API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=cURL#retrieve-a-standalone-marker). Via a GET request you are able to calculate a route between two points e.g A and B. The snippet done with jQuery could look like the following:

```
  $.get('https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/cycling/' + lngA + ',' + latA + ';' + lngB + ',' + latB + '?access_token=<your-access-token>', 
    function(data) {

    var coords = polyline.decode(data.routes[0].geometry); // Get the geometry of the request  and convert it from a Google string to coordinates 
    var line = L.polyline(coords).addTo(mapTwo);

  });
```

Regarding to your question you want to connect each marker with each other! So I have created a function to calculate the route and add this function into a double loop, to rout from each marker to each marker:

```
function calculateRoute(geomFrom, geomTo) {

  var lngFrom = geomFrom.geometry.coordinates[0]
  var latFrom = geomFrom.geometry.coordinates[1]

  var lngTo = geomTo.geometry.coordinates[0]  
  var latTo = geomTo.geometry.coordinates[1]

  $.get('https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/cycling/' + lngFrom + ',' + latFrom + ';' + lngTo + ',' + latTo + '?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicHJheWVyIiwiYSI6ImI3OGRjZjcyY2JiZTUzODMwZWUxZDdiNjRiMWE4NjI5In0.zETX-x6-XPpAv3zt4MiFwg', 
    function( data ) {
    var coords = polyline.decode(data.routes[0].geometry);

    var line = L.polyline(coords).addTo(mapTwo);

  });  
};
```

This calculates the route between each markers in a geoJSON. Here you got a little [**<< FIDDLE >>**](https://jsfiddle.net/1487xyjw/), based on your questions code. I hope this was usefull and I could help you !